# Optimizing algorithm for every pairs in an array

Tags: algorithm, optimization

For a simple algorithmic challenge, I have to make an algorithm to solve this:

> You are given an array of *n* integers, *a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>n-1</sub>*, and a positive integer, *k*. Find and print the number of *(i, j)* pairs where *i < j* and *a<sub>i</sub> + a<sub>j</sub>* is evenly divisible by *k*.

The obvious brute force algorithm is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time and *O(1)* space (I think). Pseudo-code:

```
int count;
for each (i in array) {
    for each (j in array) {
        if (i >= j)
            continue;

        if ((i + j) % k == 0)
            count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

I don't think there is a way - there probably is :) - without iterating 2 times through the array to count every pair, because every pair (except those where `i >= j` of course) has a possible chance of being evenly divisible by *k*, so I have to iterate through all of them.

So, is there any way to optimize my algorithm?

Comment: yep, you can, check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605991/number-of-subarrays-divisible-by-k

Comment: @levi I think its a bit of different problem statement than I have.

Comment: here is another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545544/optimal-algorithm-needed-for-finding-pairs-divisible-by-a-given-integer-k

Comment: @levi Nice find, I came up with the exact same algorithm, as the answerer there, so I better upvote his answer lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can walk through the array once and keep track of the number of elements that have each remainder up to `k-1`, when they are divided by `k`. That takes `O(k)` space, but allows you to solve the problem in `O(n + k)` steps, which is much better if `k` is small.

Pseudocode (AKA JavaScript):

```
function countDivisiblePairs( arr, k ) {
    const remainders = Array( k ).fill( 0 );
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        remainders[ arr[ i ] % k ]++; 
    }

    // Count the pairs of elements that were individually 
    // divisible by `k` (had a remainder of `0`), so 
    // added together they are still divisible by k
    //
    // `remainders[ 0 ]*remainders[ 0 ]` of them if we wanted all, but 
    // since we only want to count when i < j, so we subtract 
    // `remainders[0]` to get rid of the cases where `i = j` and then 
    // we divide by 2 to remove the cases where `i > j`.

    let numPairs = (remainders[ 0 ]*remainders[ 0 ] - remainders[ 0 ])/2;

    // Count the cases where the remainder wasn't 0,
    // if the remainders sum to `k`, then the sum is divisible by `k`.
    for ( let i = 1; i <= k/2; i++ ) {

        // Note that i + (k - i) = k, so each elements with a 
        // remainder of `i` can be paired with each element with
        // a remainder of `k`, but, if `k` was even there will be a 
        // final iteration where `i = (k - i)`, so we need to add a 
        // special case to only count when `i < j`, we do it the same 
        // way as we did for the case when the remainder was 0. with 
        // the if statement `(2*i === k)` is another way of writing
        // the expression `i === (k - i)`.

        if ( 2*i === k ) 
            numPairs += (remainders[ i ]*remainders[ i ] - remainders[ i ])/2;
        else
            numPairs += remainders[ i ]*remainders[ k - i ];
    }
    return numPairs;
}
```

The code above assumes that there are no duplicates in the input array. In that case you need special care EG, `[2,2,4,4,4], 2` should ouput `6` but instead outputs `10` (the correct output for `[2,4,6,8,10], 2`) but it should give you the jist of the algorithm. Output:

```
countDivisiblePairs( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 2 ); // 12
countDivisiblePairs( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3 ); // 10
countDivisiblePairs( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 4 ); // 6
countDivisiblePairs( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 5 ); // 6
```

Note that the special case in the loop only happens on the last iteration and only when `k` is even, EG. if `k` is 4, then when `i = 2`, `i === (k - i)`, so if we didn't have the special handling we would count extra elements. EG for the example output where I used a `k` of `4`, there are two elements that have a remainder of `2`: `[2,6]`. If we didn't have the extra handling it would say there are four ways to pair them, amounting to `(2,2),(2,6),(6,2),(6,6)`, but the extra logic subtracts the cases where they're paired with themselves, so we have `(2,6),(6,2)` remaining and then the division by 2 subtracts the case where `i > j`, so you're left with only one pair being counted: `(2,6)`.

Comment: Thanks :) Would you maybe mind adding comments or similar, because I don't fully grasp how the second loop works.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Sure thing

Comment: This makes sense know. Thank you very much :)